# Find a sequence of functions such that $\int u_n \ d \mu = 1$ and $\int u \ d\mu = 2$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for a sequence of positive measurable functions $u_n$ where $u_n \rightarrow u$  as $n \rightarrow \infty$ such that $\int u_n \ d \mu = 1$ and $\int u \ d\mu = 2$. I can pick my measure space myself $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu$).

Any suggestions? I keep running into negativ functions. Maybe it is not possible?

Comment: What do you mean with $u_n \rightarrow u$. I guess you mean the pointwise convergence...

Comment: Yea. I'm talking about pointwise convergence. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible by Fatou's lemma, which in this case says that $$\int u\,d\mu \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int u_n \,d\mu = 1.$$

Comment: please elaborate ...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM done

Answer (score 0):

Use $\Bbb R$ and Lebesgue.
Let $v_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&n\le x<n+1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Then $\int v_n\, \mathrm dx=1$ and $v_n\to 0$. Now let $u_n=f-v_n$ where $\int f\,\mathrm dx=2$

*Remark:* The above uses pointwise convergence. It can easily be adjusted to uniform convergence by "widening the humps", i.e., $v_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac 1n&n\le x<2n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: The question asks for a sequence of positive functions, so I don't think this works.

Comment: But how will $u_n$ be positive everywhere when you subtract $v_n$?